# MariaDB 10.9.2 memory leak

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I recently upgraded from a single node MySql 5.5 to a 3 node Galera cluster with MariDB 10.9.2. The application is Drupal. All the traffic goes to one node in the cluster, the others are basically idle (maribackup is performed on one).

The busy node leaks memory. It takes about 3-4 days before it gets killed by OOM. The memory grows way beyond what these parameters suggest:

```
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 4M
```

There are no stored procedures or triggers in the database, but a lot of tables (around 700). Usually there are 2-3 sessions active (show processlist) and cpu around 10%. Mamory is stable on the idle nodes.
This did not leak memory in MySql 5.5.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much RAM?  Swap?  Can you provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLE` after it has been running for a day (but before it crashes); this may provide more insight into what is going wrong.  Cf: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: Thanks Rick.
Ram is 12GB and swap was 2 GB when OOM killed the engine. Now I have a cron job that checks memory usage every night and restarts the engine if necessary.  In regards to GLOBAL STATUS etc, are there any particular variables of special interest?

Comment: I'll run the two lists through a few hundred formulas to see what pops up. (I don't have a specific subset.)  Many of the STATUS values are "counters", so they needed to be divided by Uptime to get a useful metric.  Maybe one of them will pop out as excessive.

Comment: [MDEV-29977](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29977) or [something else](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22memory%20leak%22%20and%20fixVersion%20in%20(10.9.3%2C%2010.9.4%2C%2010.9.5%2C%2010.9.6)), so an upgrade maybe. 10.9.2 was a very new GA.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will upgrade to 10.9.5 when available, many of these memleak bugs are fixed there.